# How can I loop through similar files and then choose another file that corresponds to the file chosen during the loop?

Tags: linux, shell, loops, unix, nested-loops

For Shell Script How can I loop through similar files and while I'm looping through these files choose another file that corresponds to the one that is chosen for the loop at that time?

Here is some of my code:

```
FILES=(/home/Practice/sm_data.*.model)

for f in "${FILES[@]}"
do

        infile1="${FILES[@]}"
        infile2= (/home/Practice/sm_data.*.source)
done
```

So, for the first time it goes through the loop I want it to choose sm_data.**1**.model (which is already does here) but then based on this I want it to find sm_data.**1**.source.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `"$f"` would give you `/home/Practice/sm_data.1.model` and `"${f%.*}.source"` would give you `/home/Practice/sm_data.1.source`

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you want, but it looks like when `$f` is `.../sm_data.foo.model`, you want to select `.../sm_data.foo.source`. If so, in the body of your loop, get rid of `infile1` completely, and simply make `infile2="${f%model}source"`. If it is something different, please explain further. (Which is essentially the same recommendation as in the other comment)